# PostgreSQL search text in column having type array

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL for storing details of films,

```
film_id serial NOT NULL,
title text,
language text,
directors text[]
```

I can write a query to find all films having a director name 'ab'

```
SELECT * FROM films  where  'ab' like any(films.directors)
```

But How can I write a query to search the table to get all films having a director name starting with 'ab',this query does not giving me any result

```
 SELECT * FROM films  where  'ab%' like any(films.directors)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two different ways (none of them really elegant):

Unnest the array and then search on the elements using `LIKE`, if you need the result as an array again, you need to aggregate (which means adding more columns than just the directors and the `film_id` is going to be complicated:

```
select film_id, array_agg(name) as directors
from (
  SELECT film_id, unnest(directors) as name
  FROM films  
) t
where name like 'ab%'
group by film_id;
```

Another option (equally slow) might be to create a long string with a delimiter out of the array and then search inside that string:

```
select *
from films
where '###'||array_to_string(directors, '###') like '%###ab%'
```

Prepending the delimiter to the string ensures that every entry starts with the delimiter and the condition `like '%###ab%'` will only match names that actually start with `ab`.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way too. The reason, your original plan could not work, is because the [array comparison expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18486) can only use an operator & an array expression on the right side of the operator:

```
<expression> operator ANY|SOME|ALL (<array expression>)
```

And all the pattern matching operators work *reversed* (on the right side there are the pattern) -- you could use that too, but only if you have a pattern array, which you want to test again a single string. this is usually not so useful, but you can [make some operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html) which work reversed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_like(text, text) RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE SQL AS 'SELECT $2 LIKE $1';
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_ilike(text, text) RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE SQL AS 'SELECT $2 ILIKE $1';
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_similarto(text, text) RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE SQL AS 'SELECT $2 SIMILAR TO $1';
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_posix_match(text, text) RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE SQL AS 'SELECT $2 ~ $1';
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_posix_imatch(text, text) RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE SQL AS 'SELECT $2 ~* $1';

CREATE OPERATOR ~~> (PROCEDURE = reverse_like, LEFTARG = text, RIGHTARG = text);
CREATE OPERATOR ~~*> (PROCEDURE = reverse_ilike, LEFTARG = text, RIGHTARG = text);
CREATE OPERATOR ~~~> (PROCEDURE = reverse_similarto, LEFTARG = text, RIGHTARG = text);
CREATE OPERATOR ~> (PROCEDURE = reverse_posix_match, LEFTARG = text, RIGHTARG = text);
CREATE OPERATOR ~*> (PROCEDURE = reverse_posix_imatch, LEFTARG = text, RIGHTARG = text);
```

After that, you can use the `ANY`/`SOME`/`ALL` array comparisons:

```
SELECT *
FROM   films
WHERE  '^ab' ~> any(films.directors);

SELECT *
FROM   films
WHERE  'ab%' ~~> any(films.directors);

SELECT *
FROM   films
WHERE  'ab%' ~~~> any(films.directors);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0ceeb/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM films
where directors like 'ab%';
```

should get you what you request.  Notice how the expressions surronding the `LIKE` operator are switched from the order they were in.

Here is a [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html) to the `SELECT` documentation for postgresql 9 which has an example of query using like as show above in my example.

`ANY` needs a subquery according to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-subquery.html

Comment: This will result in `operator does not exist: text[] ~~ unknown`. And `any` does not need a subquery when used with an array.